# Why UPDATE statement affecting less rows than SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have Select and Update query but both affecting different rows any ideas why ?

Price column settings: decimal(15,4) DEFAULT 0.0000,

Select -> Selected rows 2534

```
SELECT product_id FROM product WHERE manufacturer_id = 47
```

Update -> Affected rows 2405

```
UPDATE product SET price = ROUND(price * 1.045) WHERE manufacturer_id = 47
```

Comment: In some rows `price` is NULL or zero.

Comment: @Akina price row is set decimal(15,4) DEFAULT VALUE 0.000

Comment: Affected rows in UPDATE is the amount of the rows updated by fact. If new value is equal to old one then this row is not counted as updated.

Comment: Investigate. Add the column into the structure temporarily with default value of 0, and assign it to 1 in UPDATE. Then select the rows with this column equal to 0 and try to understand the source of difference between them and updated columns.\

Comment: Please share more details - why not check the affected rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When after update result is the same as before, that row isn't count as affected. In this case, when price is equal to ROUND(price * 1.045) that row wouldn't be affected.

So look at [ROUND()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/round/) function. It return rounded value to number of decimal places given by second argument. If second argument is ommited, then it means 0 decimal places and return integer.

So if x * 1.054 is less then x.5 it return x.

Comment: thats right price between 1-11 * 1.045 return same value